# cypher query get wrong results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph which contains 3 types of nodes : Post, User, Cat, every cat have so many posts that are linked together with a 'next' relationship, every user can comment on these posts and the comment is a 'Commented' relationship with a 'content' and 'id' property. 
 
I want to get the posts of some cat and all the comments related to every post. 

I've tried this but it don't give me posts without comments:

```
MATCH (cat:Cat {id:1})-[:lastPost]->(last)-[:next*0..]->(rest)
MATCH (rest)<-[c:Commented]-(u:User)
RETURN c, rest
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want in Cypher ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the second `MATCH` statement to an `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (cat:Cat {id:1})-[:lastPost]->(last)-[:next*0..]->(rest)
OPTIONAL MATCH (rest)<-[c:Commented]-(u:User)
RETURN c, rest
```

Any values that don't match the `OPTIONAL MATCH` pattern will be `NULL`.

Comment: thank you ,, it works ,, if I want to get theses result in c# using neo4jclient should I use Pair or something like that ?

Comment: @Rawhi I'm not too familiar with neo4jclient, but [here](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#get-a-user-and-the-count-of-their-friends) is a neo4jclient example using an `OPTIONAL MATCH` statement.